# Skip Spring Flux Security on the basis of some header values

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

My requirement is pretty different, Actually I've added security in Spring Cloud API Gateway (WebFlux based) and Now Basically I want to skip OAuth resource server complete flow on the basis of some header values if exists on endpoints /testAPI/** otherwise
OAuth resource server flow will be initiated on the same endpoints /testAPI/**

> SecurityConfig

```java
    @Autowired
    private ReactiveAuthenticationManager manager;
    

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange()
                
                .pathMatchers("/testAPI/**").authenticated()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and()
                
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt()
                    .authenticationManager(manager)
                .and()
                .and()
                
                .addFilterBefore(new SecurityWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                
                .build();
```

And in SecurityWebFilter, I tried ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(..) with custom Authentication by setting it to true and also with

```java
Mono<Authentication> authentication = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .doOnSuccess(auth -> {
                    auth.setAuthenticated(true);
                });
```

Nothing is working for me, I'm able to validate with OAuth server but I want to skip it conditionally on same endpoints.

Please help, I'm New to WebFlux and exploring spring security.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom matcher

```java
private ServerWebExchangeMatcher authorizationHeaderMatcher() {
        return (exchange) -> exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
                ? MatchResult.match()
                : MatchResult.notMatch();

    }
```

and Configured the same in SecurityConfig

```java
.securityMatcher(customAuthorizationMatcher())
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/testAPI/**").authenticated()
```